# innerHTML event with multiple Youtube players (change navbar with javascript API)

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, embed, innerhtml

I'm trying to change the content of my navbar when a youtube embed is played, so the user sees on witch item of the navbar the sound(/video) is coming from. It works fine with one player but theres an issue when you have two players. Because if two embeds are playing and pause is pressed on one of them, it looks like none is playing on the navbar.

What i'm trying to do is make 1 item (number 10) on my navbar react to multiple youtube players. So if i press play, number 10 lights up red, if i press pause (or stop) it goes white again (the original colour). This works great with one player but doesn't work with two (or more). Because if it press play on two players, the navbar item turns red. But if pauze 'one' of them, the navbar item turns white, while the other play is still playing.

What i want is the 'go white' event to look at two players, so if the other player is still playing, i want the navbar item to remain red, only if both players stop, it should go white.

I need the 'go white' event to say: turn white only if both players are not playing

(hope this is better then te previous explanation)

NAVBAR:

```
 </li>
  <li><a id="c10" href="#as10">10</a></li>
  <li><a id="c09" href="#as9">9</a></li>
  <li><a id="c08" href="#as8">8</a></li>
  ....
</ul>
```

EMBEDS:

```
<iframe id="player1" name="t136" width="240" height="220" data-src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/IpMqzFdt5fU?rel=0&showinfo=2&controls=2" enablejsapi="1" onload=lzld(this) frameborder="0" controls="2" allowfullscreen src="about:blank" onload=lzld(this)>

<iframe id="player2" name="t137" width="240" height="220" data-src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/CwYo5DzFzQ4?rel=0&showinfo=2&controls=2" enablejsapi="1" frameborder="0" controls="2" allowfullscreen src="about:blank" onload=lzld(this)> </iframe>
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player1' , {
  events: {
    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
  }
 });
player = new YT.Player('player2' , {
  events: {
    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
     });
  }
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
      if (event.data == 1 ) {
        var element=document.getElementById("c10");
element.innerHTML="<font color=red>10</font>";}
    if (event.data == 2 || event.data == 0) {var element=document.getElementById("c10");
element.innerHTML="10";};
  }

</script>
```

**NEW PROBLEM**

I've come across a'n issue with innerhtml event when using an iframe refresh button, witch looks like this:

HTML:

```
<a class="pull-right" href="#" onclick="Click1()">refresh</a>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function Click1(){
  document.getElementById('player1').src = document.getElementById('player1').src;
  players["player1"] = [new YT.Player("player1", { events: { 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange }}), false];
  if (allStopped==true) {document.getElementById("c10").innerHTML = "10";}
```

the problem again is that if the user presses refresh while playing an embed, the navbar stays red, while it should be white (if nothing is playing). I had the same issue before, but i can't get it to work with a click event.  This time you can be certain that the refresh causes a playback stop, but other embeds could be playing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: *Updated code and description below to reflect the updates to the original post*

Two things of possible use to you: 1) in your onYouTubePlayerAPIReady method, you'll want to use an array to hold the references to the two players (so you aren't overwriting the first one with the second). IF you don't do this, then you won't hear events from the first player object any more. This approach will also let you keep track of which players are playing, so that when a pause event comes up, the state is stored for you to find out if ALL players have stopped and you need to make your navbar change. 2) note that the event element not only has the data, but also has a 'target' attribute which will contain the ID of the player which raised the event. So you ought to be able to use that info to let your onPlayerStateChange method know what to do to you navbar. Something like this might get at what you need:

```
var players = {};
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
        players[iframes[i].id] = [new YT.Player(iframes[i].id, {
            events: {
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        }), false] // the 'false' in this array is whether or not it's currently playing
    }
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == 1) {
        document.getElementById("c10").innerHTML = "<span style='color:red'>10</span>";
        players[event.target.a.id][1] = true;
    }
    if (event.data == 2 || event.data == 0) {
        var allStopped = true;
        players[event.target.a.id][1] = false;
        for (var frame in players) {
            if (players[frame][1] == true) {
                allStopped = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (allStopped == true) {
            document.getElementById("c10").innerHTML = "10";
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a fiddle of this code that demonstrates it's working:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlmcdonald/VA64N/9/

Comment: HI! sry for the bad explanation, but thnx for your reaction!! I made some changes to my original explanation. What i'm trying to do is have one piece of text (in your fiddle you had two) for two youtube players. problem: when you press pause on one, it doesnt look if the other player is still playing. I nEEED this:)

Comment: Makes more sense, now. I've updated the code and description above to meet your requirements--see if it's behaving as it ought to!

Comment: sorry... small side question: i've added a refresh button for each player like this: <a href="#" onclick="iframe.contentWindow.location.reload(player1);">refresh</a>, buton when refresh is pressed the whole thing (discribed above) doesn't work. How can it be that when a iframe is refreshed, the javascript that it uses is canceled?

Comment: maybe it's interesting why I want to have a refresh button: because i have a lot of embeds on 1 page, when too many are loaded, flash tends to crash, but when you refresh a player, it onloads because i have '&controls=2' inside the youtubelink

Comment: When you refresh the iframe, the API will lose the bindings to the player. So your onclick event would need to call a function that reloads the iframe and then, when it's loaded, creates another YT.player object. Something like this (assuming it's player1 you're reloading): players["player1"] = [new YT.Player("player1", { events: { 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange }}), false]

Comment: can't get it to work:( this is what i made of it: onclick="var ifr=document.getElementsByName('player1')[0]; ifr.src=ifr.src; players["player1"] = [new YT.Player("player1", { events: { 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange }}), false];"

Comment: oops! did get it to work just had to put the javascript code outside of the onclick event:) thnx for everything!!

Comment: I found out that another problem is accuring, promise this is the last one. When refresh is pressed, i need it to look at if something is playing, before making the navbar item white again. Same issue, but could implement is with this click event. Tried every combination of code... :( I suck (put the code in a new section above)

Comment: Try this ... as the first line of your function, tell the player to pause before it refreshes. That way, the pause event will be raised and it should make use of the event handler you already have in place (hence changing the color). should be something like this: players["player1"].pauseVideo();

Comment: great idea! just can't get the pause function to work; put it in your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VA64N/10/

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it a better idea might be just to add to your event handler so that, when a new video is cued, it checks to see if anything is playing. Check out the edited fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/VA64N/11/) and look specifically for this line: if (event.data == 2 || event.data == 0 || event.data == 5) { // when the event data is equal to 5, that's a 'video cued' event)

Comment: added event.data == 5 but it doesn't make the navbar item white when onclick is activated (get an error when loading your new fiddle)

Comment: Hmmm--this is an interesting question. Looks like the actual reloading of the iframe doesn't call the cued video event (likely because it isn't the player doing the reloading, but the browser). So that's out. I played with the fiddle a bit and, when putting in a pauseVideo before the reload, that does work; however, it revealed a new problem. Reloading the iframe in the way that you do (which you need to do in order to avoid browser security measures) makes it so the iframe isn't addressable by the YT Player Api, so a second refresh throws an error. Maybe raise this as a separate SO question?

Comment: WILLDO! could you show how you made the pause event work (without the refresh stuff)

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you again. But you gave me the impression that you figured out how to implement a pauseVideo function with the code above, I need this before I can tackle the refresh issue with a new question.  @jlmcdonald